# Handling Rails form_for in a view not connected to the form_for controller.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, model-view-controller

So after quite sometime and a slight headache. I was able to get a `Rails` versioned form working. Although I was able to get it working, I dont know if it is the best practice as it feels a little off. I have a website that has a form for signing up on the landing page. The landing page is `static_pages#home`. I have created a partial for my users controller `_new.html.erb` that has been included on my landing page. Here is the form that I have:

```
<!-- Main Form -->
<div class="login-form-1">
  <!-- <form id="register-form" class="text-left"> -->
    <div class="login-form-main-message"></div>
    <div class="main-login-form">
      <div class="login-group">
        <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.text_field :first_name, :class => "form-control", :placeholder => "First Name" %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.text_field :last_name, :class => "form-control", :placeholder => "Last Name" %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.text_field :user_name, :class => "form-control", :placeholder => "User Name" %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.email_field :email, :class => "form-control", :placeholder => "Email" %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="login-button"><%= f.submit "", :class => "remove-button" %></button>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <div class="etc-login-form">
      <p>already have an account? <a href="#">login here</a></p>
    </div>
  <!-- </form> -->
</div>
<!-- end:Main Form -->
```

It is a little messy because I have added a lot of styling. The thing to pay attention to is how I am presenting the `form_for`. I have passed to it an object of `@user`. Normally this `@user` would be found in the `Users#new` action; however, the only way to get this form to function properly is to have the `Static_pages#home` handle it by setting `@user = User.new`. Doing this seems incorrect, however, I cannot seem to find a better way of going about this. Initially all I'm looking to do is have this form when submitted, hit the `Users#create` action. I have tried passing `form_for` (:user, :users, "/users"), but when I try this it attempts to hit a `Static_pages#create` action.

All in all, my question revolves around if this is a correct way of handling this, and if not what would be a more appropriate way. Again, I was able to get this to work, but that is by setting `@user = User.new` every time the `Static_pages#home`, my landing page, is visited. Thank you for your time in answering this.

Answer (score 0):

This is ok and perfectly acceptable. I would even be tempted to write `form_for User.new`.

Please remember that in most "realistic" pages, more than 1 resource can be found. E.g. a login form on the about page, a tag-cloud on the posts page, so a controller might need to retrieve more than 1 type of object.

Theoretically, if your page is made up of disconnected/independent areas (e.g. 1 area=a post and its comments, and another is the list of most recent comments), you could also consider using [cells](https://github.com/apotonick/cells).

Comment: I would keep the @user = User.new so the newly instantiated object can be referenced.

Comment: Yeah, to maintain the MVC model I want to stay away from `User.new` in my view. Great advice so far though, thank you.